# Reverse for 'fleet' not found. 'fleet' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I am getting the above error when I try to access the landing page.

What am I missing?

Traceback

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'fleet' not found. 'fleet' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'fleet' not found. 'fleet' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Here is the base.html code

```
<button>
  `<a href="{% url 'trucks:fleet' %}"> Fleet Admin </a>
</button>
```

and below is the app urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path

from .admin import fleet_admin_site

app_name = 'trucks'

urlpatterns = [
  path('fleet/', fleet_admin_site.urls, name="fleet"),
]
```

and the main urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, reverse

from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', include('workers.urls')),
  path('admin/', include('trucks.urls')),
  path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html')),
]
```

admin.py file where I extend the AdminSite

```
class FleetAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
  site_header = ''
  site_title = ''
  index_title = ''


fleet_admin_site = FleetAdminSite(name='fleet_admin')
```

Comment: There is likely still another `{% url 'fleet' %}` in your template (so without the `trucks:` namespace), you need to add that namespace.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem none. I only have two urls. {% url 'trucks:fleet' %} and {% url 'workers:staff' %}

Comment: what this line means **fleet_admin_site.urls** ? urls is method name ?

Comment: and I can access both of them directly

Comment: @c.grey extension of AdminSite

Comment: @Alasdair just added part of **admin.py**  file where **fleet_admin_site** is defined. I do not have a **fleet_admin_site.urls** file. am just extending django-admin to accomodate both apps but different admin users

Comment: @Alasdair thanks for heads up. **{% url 'trucks:fleet_admin:index' %}** worked but now trying to access the url am getting **'admin' is not a registered namespace** error

Comment: @Alasdair nvm. Thanks alot for the help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

by seeing your code 
you need to add method or class not any extension

```
  path('fleet/', fleet_admin_site.urls, name="fleet"),

  path(route, view, kwargs=None, name=None)
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/)

Answer (score 0):

You are including the fleet admin with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('fleet/', fleet_admin_site.urls, name="fleet"),
]
```

You can't do `{% url 'trucks:fleet' %}` to reverse `fleet_admin_site.urls`. You need to [reverse a particular admin URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).

For example, to reverse the index, you would do:

```
{% 'trucks:fleet_admin:index' %}
```

In the above, you use `trucks` because you have `app_name = 'trucks'` in the `urls.py`, `fleet_admin` because that is the namespace in `fleet_admin_site = FleetAdminSite(name='fleet_admin')`, and `index` because that's the view you want to reverse.

Finally, the `name` in your `path()` doesn't have any effect, so I would remove it.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('fleet/', fleet_admin_site.urls),
]
```